# Redis Lua script to delete a number of keys stored in a set

Tags: redis, lua

I am holding a list of keys in a set: `SADD keys a b c`.

From a Redis Lua script, I need to remove all keys stored in the `keys` set. This is what I have in mind:

```
local keys = redis.call("SMEMBERS", KEYS[1])
redis.call("DEL", unpack(keys))
```

My question is, is this *okay*? I know that all keys used in a Lua script should be passed via the `KEYS` table. Would my example pose any issues, when using multiple Redis instances? If so, how should I tackle this issue?

Comment: If you are running a single Redis instance, IMHO, it's not a big deal. However, if you're running Redis Cluster, these keys might located on other slots, and the `DEL` command will fail.

Comment: @for_stack How would I make this right for Redis Cluster?

Comment: You can use hash tag to ensure that all keys located in a single slot, then you can delete these keys with a single `DEL`.

Comment: @for_stack how is using a hash different than using a set?

Comment: hash tag is NOT HASH, it's a solution to ensure all keys with the same hash tag to be located in the same slot. Check the [doc](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) for detail.